# Proving a sequence has a finite Limit

Tags: calculus, limits

I was wondering how to prove that a sequence is converging to a finite limit.

I know that if a sequence is bounded and decreasing / increasing then it has a finite limit.

although I have 2 questions where I don't know how to prove them :

the sequence : $a_n = \frac {1}{n} + \frac {1}{n+1} + ... \frac {1}{3n}$

This sequence is bounded between 1 and 3 , I tried to prove its decreasing but failed to.

the sequence : $a_n = \frac {1}{\sqrt{1}} + \frac {1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac {1}{\sqrt{3}} + ...+ \frac {1}{\sqrt{n}}$
is not bounded and has no finite limit ($\infty$)

what is the way to prove?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

$$a_n=\frac 1n+\frac{1}{n+1}+...+\frac{1}{3n}$$

$$a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{n+1}+...+\frac{1}{3n}+\frac{1}{3n+1}+\frac{1}{3n+2}+\frac{1}{3(n+1)}$$

then

$$a_{n+1}-a_n=$$
$$\frac{1}{3n+1}+\frac{1}{3n+2}+\frac{1}{3n+3}-\frac 1n=$$
$$\frac{.......}{n(3n+1)(3n+2)(3n+3)}$$

For the second sequence, use the fact that for any $ k\in\{1,2,...n\}$,

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$
to get
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\ge \frac{n}{\sqrt{n}}$$

Observe that the RHS goes to infinity and conclude.

Comment: The professor didn't teach any integrals yet , I though there is no limit for the second sequence.

Comment: @Ivan Ok, i edited with No integral.

Comment: oh ok thank you, I got it. I did similar with the squeeze theorem and showed its bounded between $\infty$ so the limit can not be finite one.

Answer (score 2):

The following shows that $a_{n}\geq a_{n+1}$ for all $n$, that is, $(a_{n})$ is decreasing:

$\frac {1}{n}  + ... + \frac {1}{3n} > \frac {1}{n+1}+...+\frac{1}{3n+1}+\frac{1}{3n+2}+\frac{1}{3n+3} \Longleftrightarrow \frac {1}{n}>\frac{1}{3n+1}+\frac{1}{3n+2}+\frac{1}{3n+3}$

Since $\frac {1}{n} > \frac {1}{n+\frac {1}{3}}=\frac {3}{3n+1}= \frac {1}{3n+1}+\frac {1}{3n+1}+\frac {1}{3n+1} > \frac{1}{3n+1}+\frac{1}{3n+2}+\frac{1}{3n+3}$, the result follows.

Comment: Good Idea (+1){}{}{}{}{}

Comment: Thank you, +1 to you too.